# Uninstall Visual Studio Core in CentOS

Tags: visual-studio, terminal, centos, uninstallation, .net-core

I installed Visual Studio Core in CentOS (7) but the core command cannot be found. I want to uninstall and re-install from terminal this time around. What is the command in terminal to uninstall Visual Studio Core in CentOS (7)? I googled this and the answers I found are for non-CentOS Linux like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the command. Sometimes things are simple:

```
sudo yum remove code
```

Comment: since you already share the solution for your issue and it is better to mark it as answer and this will help other community members who have the same or similar to search and confirm this solution.

Comment: Hi @Sara I can't accept my own answer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Hi, I just recommend you mark your reply as answer, that can help others to find the right solution once that they have the same issue. I’m sorry for that if I made any mistake.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I can accept my own answer in a few hours, I'll check back and thanks for the note!